# Scala value has incompatible type?

Tags: scala, types

I am still new enough to Scala that the typing system is destroying me. I haven't yet thought of a solution or discovered a pattern that gets around this particular problem that I am trying to solve. Consider the following program:

**ShapeType.scala**

```
package models

abstract class ShapeType {
  val themes: ShapeThemes[ShapeTheme] // I think this is where the problem is...?
}

class CircleShapeType extends ShapeType {
  val themes = CircleShapeThemes
}

object CircleShapeType extends CircleShapeType
```

**ShapeThemes.scala**

```
package models

abstract class ShapeThemes[T <: ShapeTheme] {
  val themes: List[T]
}

class CircleShapeThemes extends ShapeThemes[CircleShapeTheme] {
  val themes = List(
    new CircleShapeTheme,
    new CircleShapeTheme,
    new CircleShapeTheme
  )
}

object CircleShapeThemes extends CircleShapeThemes
```

**ShapeTheme.scala**

```
package models

class ShapeTheme

class CircleShapeTheme extends ShapeTheme
```

When I attempt to compile the program (using [sbt](http://www.scala-sbt.org/)), I get the following error:

```
[error] /Users/mjs/Projects/sandbox/shape-types/src/main/scala/ShapeType.scala:8: overriding value themes in class ShapeType of type models.ShapeThemes[models.ShapeTheme];
[error]  value themes has incompatible type
[error]   val themes = CircleShapeThemes
[error]       ^
[error] one error found
[error] (compile:compile) Compilation failed
[error] Total time: 2 s, completed Mar 14, 2015 5:08:43 PM
```

However, as far as I can tell, `CircleShapeThemes` is a `ShapeThemes[ShapeTheme]`. What am I missing?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`CircleShapeThemes` is *not* a `ShapeThemes[ShapeTheme]`, it's a `ShapeThemes[CircleShapeTheme]`.

"But", you may object, "a `CircleShapeTheme` is a `ShapeTheme`!  Indeed, but that subclass relationship isn't propagated by default.  You have to ask for it by making the type parameter *covariant*: `abstract class ShapeThemes[+T <: ShapeTheme]`

Comment: Brilliant. That was the missing key. Thank you!